# Why does RedirectToRoute("Default") not redirect to the root?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given these routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Test", "test", new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If I call RedirectToRoute("Default") from the Index action of the TestController it redirects to `/test` but I expected it to redirect to `/`

I checked the result of calling RedirectToRoute("Default") before returning it during a debugging session.

RedirectToRouteResult result = RedirectToRoute("Default");

It has a property RouteName with a value "Default" and a property RouteValues with no elements (Count = 0). I checked using Reflector, and null is passed internally as the RouteValueDictionary.

Again, I would expect that given the defaults for the route defined in my application, it would redirect to Index view on the HomeController.

Why doesn't it redirect to `/`?

Comment: Is `/test` your application root? Or `/` is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RouteValueDictionary filled in to the current action is being used to fill in the Controller, Action, ID. This is usually the functionality you want and lets you do things like `<%:Html.ActionLink("MyAction")%>` without needing to specify your controller in a view.

To force it to the complete fall back default just use:

`RedirectToRoute("default", null");`

The second argument is for your routevalues and by specifying it you override the preexisting values.

However I would say the preferred way would be to have a Home route which will not take any parameters. This means your redirects will not need a load of nulls floating around and a call to `RedirectToRoute("Home")` is also nice and explicit.

**Edit**

This is a really old answer and as a couple of people have mentioned doesn't seem to have been working for them. For what it's worth I now don't use this pattern and explicitly override controller and area when I need to break out. Not only does it apparently work better but when you come back to the code it's good to see explicitly that you're coming out of this context and mean to blank out certain routevalues.

For the record I have also tended more towards named route based URL generation over convention based generation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that "null" parameter Chao mentions has ever worked for me.  Perhaps it did in prior MVC versions, but now in MVC 5.2 this is the only way I can get it to work:

```
RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "", action = "" });
```

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the actual code to see what is going on it can be a bit tricky to know why, but this [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1329067.aspx) post does shed some light. The answerer says that under the covers it might be creating a `RouteValueDictionary` which would contain the controller and action you are currently in, which in your case would be a controller of Test and an action of Index. Then, when you call `RedirectToRoute("Default")`, the controller and the action in the RouteValueDictionary will be used when matching the default route and you will be taken to the Index action in your Test controller.

Now you could always do a `Redirect("/")` to take you to the main page of your site.

Comment: Redirect("/") will redirect to the domain root. This is a problem if your site is hosted in a subdirectory within that domain.